# How to print colors text in the spring shell with Java?

Tags: java, console, command-line-interface, spring-shell

In my spring shell app i'm using the following code to print colored text but it's not works for me.
  Note: this works in netbeans ideas console and prints "sampleText" in red color, but does not in windows cmd.

here is my code:

```
    String ANSI_RESET = "\u001B[0m";
    String ANSI_RED = "\u001B[31m";
    System.out.println(ANSI_RED + "sampleText" + ANSI_RESET);
```

out put:

```
←[31msampleText←[0m
```

Answer (score 0):

Just have your command return `org.jline.utils.AttributedCharSequence` (or similar `AttributedXXX` classes) and they will handled automatically (by [AttributedCharSequenceResultHandler](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-shell/blob/6e6154a80a5aef9b4963806ff4880e373c87d54d/spring-shell-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/shell/result/AttributedCharSequenceResultHandler.java))

Comment: Thanks. but i don't know how can i do that, would you explain it more?

Comment: This is output: Unable to create a system terminal, creating a dumb terminal (enable debug logging for more information)

←[31msampleText←[0m

Answer (score 0):

use:
`System.out.print()`
instead of:
`System.out.println()`

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.